# How do I install the Chromium package in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, chromium, tchromium

I downloaded the necessary from http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/ with TortoiseSVN, but I do not know how to use it in Delphi XE2. How do I install the TChromium component?

Comment: for install use the DCEF_XE2.dpk file. For use you need to deploy the dlls that you can find into the bin\Win32 folder

Comment: Please look into the general subject of how to install component packages. Any well-known package, especially one like Chromium, should come with instructions on how to install it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install the component, open the appropriate package - in your case, DCEF_XE2.dpk in packages directory and install the package.

Comment: Done, but TChromium component is not in the tool palette.

Comment: Did you just "Build" or completely "Install" the package(s)? And which palette tab are you looking in? You may need to open a new form before you can see the new component in the palette.

Comment: Double click on DCEF_XE2.dpk, Delphi XE2 opened, Project > Build All Projects, when done, I opened a new VCL Application Form, but TChromium component is not in the palette.

Comment: "Build" only builds the package, it doesn't install it in the IDE. The "Install" option is available in the context menu when you right-click the project in the Project Inspector.