# How to install Delphi Chromium Embedded in Delphi XE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, chromium-embedded

I searched here and found that, but is about XE2, I searched in package folder but there's no dpk for XE, is there any way to instal for XE?

[How do I install the Chromium package in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124690/how-do-i-install-the-chromium-package-in-delphi)

I tried with D7 package but got 
[DCC Fatal Error] DCEF_D7.dpk(35): F1026 File not found: 'cefgui.dcu'

Comment: Take the XE2 code and make it compile on XE

Comment: Indeed, sometimes downgrading newer code to older versions works better than upgrading older code to newer versions.

Comment: I have a german environment so I can just *try* to translate. Sounds like missing entries in Tools/Options/Environment/DelphiOptions/Library >> LibraryPath and Searchpath would need to include the src Path of your download.