# How can I open Delphi Chromium Embedded 3 gui correctly?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, delphi-10-seattle

I downloaded dcef3 and found some demos in it. I copied contents of "src" directry to "minimal" directory and it worked fine. But when I do this to guiclient directory, I get error while opening the project:

> Class TChromium not found

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I solved this regarding to this answer: [How do I install the Chromium package in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124690/how-do-i-install-the-chromium-package-in-delphi#14125100)

- I opened the project "minimal"
- Right-clicked "cefclient" on the project manager
- Clicked "Install"

Now I'm able to open the other demo (gui project)